# Outputting the input text in a new screen

Tags: python, kivy

Basically i'm trying to take some input from a user, perform some actions, and then output the result in a new screen (i'm thinking as the label of the new screen). I've managed to switch between screens but i cannot figure out how to output the input from the first screen to the second screen. I've tried to make the input data a global variable so i can assign to the text of the label of the output screen, but it didn't work. Here's my python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from plyer import filechooser
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

g_data = 'xstring'

class MainWindow(Screen):

    def get_data(self):
        global g_data
        g_data = self.ids.user_input.text


class OutputScreen(Screen):
    def ex(self):
        self.ids.output_label.text = g_data

class mainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def change_screen(self):
        screemanager = self.root.ids['screenmanager']
        screemanager.current = 'output'

    def change(self):
        self.change_screen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  mainApp().run()
```

and my kv file:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
GridLayout:
    cols:1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screenmanager
        MainWindow:
            id: main
            name: 'main'
        OutputScreen:
            id: output
            name: 'output'

<MainWindow>:
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: user_input
            pos_hint:{"x" : 0.05, "top" : 0.9}
            size_hint: 0.9, 0.37
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"top" : 0.51, "x" : 0.05}
            size_hint: (None,None)
            width : 150
            height : 40
            font_size : 23
            text:'Submit'
            on_release: app.change()

<OutputScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: output_label
            text: root.ex()
            color: 0,0,0,1
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get your example to work, but you would need to do this:

```
g_data = ''  # new global variable defined

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def get_data(self):
        global g_data  # global goes here
        g_data = self.ids.user_input.text


class OutputScreen(Screen):
    def ex(self):
        self.ids.output_label.text = g_data
```

Comment: Hi @NameKhan72, thank you again for all of your help. I've tried your suggestion and i'm getting the following error.  ValueError: None is not allowed for Label.text

Comment: No worries. In the first line of my snippet, we define g_data to be an empty string. This can only mean, that whatever function you're overriding g_data in, sets its value to `None`. I actually don't see, where you call the get_data() function, that sets g_data. If you do indeed call it, try changing the line to:  g_data = "somestring" just to see if the global variable does it's job.

Comment: I'm not calling it, i was using to so i could store the input data in a global variable and then refer to it in the OutputScreen class. I presume i'm doing it wrong. Also when i set the g_data variable as "some_example", i'm still getting the same error as before. Please feel free if you have any suggestions. Thank you :)

Comment: The first line in the snippet - try setting *that* to some value. If you're not calling the function, the value is never set. That still doesn't explain why it gets set to None, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Then the problem lies elsewhere. I just tested my snippet again, and it has worked. Could you update your code, so I can run it? Then I could take a closer look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230100/discussion-between-olive-yew-and-namekhan72).